# CKeditor generate wrong image path

Tags: php, ckeditor, lighttpd

When I upload an image in CKeditor, the default image url is relative to the server root not to the web server (ie: `/var/www/mywebsite/images/foo.jpg instead of /mywebsite/images/foo.jpg`).
Tough the image is uploaded to the right path, I don't understand where the problem comes from.

My webserver is a lighttpd on a debian squeeze, the same web app on another webserver works great.

I don't know if it's a bad server config, or something else.